# how to detect when an Iframe change location without onload event and trigger a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to detect when my IFrame changes the location, but not using onload event, actually i need to trigger a function just after the location of the IFrame changes to validate just a list of urls and if the new location is in my list do something on the parent view.
this is my actual function that i need to trigger but just before the iframe new url start to loads thats why the event onload doesn't match with what i need

```
function onLoadFrame() {
        var a = document.getElementById("cont").contentWindow.location.href;
        if ((a.indexOf("MainDashboard") > -1) || (a.indexOf("AccountManagement") > -1) || (a.indexOf("workspace_home") > -1)) {
            $('#nav-bar').fadeOut(0);
            $('#u-left-panel').fadeOut(0);
            $("#content").css({ marginLeft: "0px" });
        } else {
            $('#nav-bar').fadeIn(0);
            $('#u-left-panel').fadeIn(0);
            $("#content").css({ marginLeft: "40px" });
        }
    }
```

**Update**
actually i needed to validate the new url or location that was being loaded in the frame in order to trigger a function that show or hide the navigation bar deppending on the new url so it wouldn't seem like delayed

Comment: Have whatever is triggering the url change in the iframe call a function in your parent?  Not nearly as nice, but have a function that polls the iframe's location? Or try the second answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection

Comment: Is the iframe content from your own site or it can be any site's content?

Comment: the content on the frame would be an url of my own site and im triggering the function onloadframe with the event onload, this is the iframe code `<iframe src="~/Dash/MainDashboard" name="contenido" id="cont" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" onload="onLoadFrame()">`

Comment: Then just follow @RobertMcKee's links and tip ... it has the solution for you.

Comment: actually the onload event triggers after the iframe finish to load everything so the function that i need to trigger trigger after the iframe content is ready and that doesn't works for me...i need to change IFrame src, then trigger the function and just after that start to load the content of the new url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out how to do the functionality i was seeking for with help from here:
[How can I get Iframe event before load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915725/how-can-i-get-iframe-event-before-load)
this is my final code that kind of hi-jack the links to get the functionality

```
 $('a[target="contenido"]').bind('click', function () {
        activateNavBar($(this).attr("href"));
    });
    function bindFunctionToLinks() {
        $("#cont").contents().find('a[target = "contenido"]').bind("click", function () {
            activateNavBar($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    }
```