# how to Trigger a submit button when Iframe url change

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I use a third party iframe src, and I want to submit my form when the Iframe src change...
how to trigger the submit button when the inner Iframe source change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`how to trigger the submit button when the inner Iframe source change?`

You can't access iframe content if it belongs to different domain.

`I use a third party iframe src`

So defenitly not as its other domain

Also from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp)

`Note: Because of security reasons, the contents of a document can be accessed from another document only if the two documents are located in the same domain.`

Comment: thank you, but if I create the iframe, cant I use a function that check if the src of my iframe has changed?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977930/is-it-possible-to-tell-if-the-src-of-an-iframe-has-changed   and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235994/how-to-determine-if-the-location-of-the-iframe-has-changed

Comment: In second link check @Daniel Vassallo answer he is saying same thing that i told.. try this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372391/alert-when-iframe-url-changed

Answer (score 0):

I changed the redirected page and add on it

```
<body onload="parent.parent.send()">
```

On the main page (where the iframe located) I add:

```
<script>
function send()
{
document.getElementById("gform_1").submit();
}
</script>
```

It solve my problem.