# How to get a response from different domain?

Tags: jquery, html, json, iframe

I have a form with multiple fields , in that form i also have a iframe which is calling another page from different domain which also contains a form, now on submitting the main form, i need to check whether the iframe form is submitted or not. How to validate that?

main page
`<iframe src="http://www.differntdomain.com/index.html"></iframe>`

index.html  also has a form

i need to check that the form is submitted in main page form submission.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to bind to the onload event of the iframe. This event is triggered every time the location is changed (which is probably the case when the form is submitted). More info here:
[iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2429045/508702)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but its not working the way i required, can you suggest some other way out please.. @Baszz

Comment: Okay @Baszz, i am not getting any alert. Both are in different domains. One app is in jsp and the other is in php. From Jsp form, i am calling the php app and then want to make sure that its form gets submitted in the jsp form.