# How to get redirect url before onload happens if no control on the redirection?

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe, dom-events

I've got an iframe which contains a web part I got no control. The web part contains some redirection functionality.

The problem is, the redirect page loads in the iframe instead of the top window. I tried forcing the redirection to the top window by adding in the `head`:

```
<base target="_search" />
<base target="_top" />
<base target="_parent" />
```

But without any success (I guess it's because there's no any `<a></a>` inside the iframe?).

So I tried another solution, like in here: [iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection) and this is my code:

```
if (ifrm.attachEvent)
    ifrm.attachEvent('onload', OnIframeRedirect);
else
    ifrm.addEventListener('load', OnIframeRedirect, false);

function OnIframeRedirect() {
    var redirectUrl = this.contentWindow.location;
    if (redirectUrl.pathname.indexOf('PartOfTheIframeSrc') == -1)
    // When the iframe is not loading it's original src
    top.window.location.href = redirectUrl;
}
```

This worked. But because `OnIframeRedirect` is happened after `onload`, users can still see the redirected page before `top.window.location` changes.

So I would like to know, if anyone has an idea how to get the redirect url before the onload happens?

Comment: Why don’t you just hide the iframe?

Comment: @David I tried `hide()` and `remove()` inside the `if` of `OnIframeRedirect`, however they are still too slow to hide the redirected content inside the iframe. Don't know what delayed the `OnIframeRedirect` function...