# Onload to early, waiting for redirect inside the frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload

I have 3 iFrames.

TP 1 = Source is fixed. No need to change something here.
TP 2 = The Source =  User Input.

The Source of TP2 needs to get checked. If the input of the user doesn't match my database query, there is a location.href redirect inside this iFrame

TP 3 = Source of TP1+TP2

I'm trying to change the source of TP3 afterwards with:

```
var geturl1 = document.getElementById('tp1').contentDocument.location;
var geturl2 = document.getElementById('tp2').contentDocument.location;

document.getElementById("tp3").src="http://example.com/load/kachi/#!/" + geturl1 + "$$" + geturl2;
```

So far so good, it is working, but unfortunately the geturl2 just shows me the old URL. Not the URL after the redirect happened.

I tried to add a onload to my TP3 iFrame, but onload thinks, the load is done, and is not working with the redirect inside the iFrame.

How can i fix this? It's about 1-2 seconds. The TP3 iFrame loads, checks if the URL is right, if not redirect. And i need to get the updated URL of this redirect.

Comment: You could use the `onload` event in your iframe. The code you place inside it will execute when the URL changes.

Comment: I already tried that, same result. I guess because technically the iframe loaded completly, and 1-2 seconds after that there is a redirect.

Comment: Does the approach mentioned here works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14111995/1054638

Comment: No, it's not :-(

Comment: I just added a 1 second set timeout to my function now.. working