# Modify iFrame Size of Google Docs Form on Submit

Tags: iframe, google-docs

I have a page where a Google Docs Form is embedded with an iFrame. The Form is quite long, so I ended up setting the length of the iFrame to 1600. Once the user clicks submit, the iFrame changes to display the confirmation which is very short. However, the user is still viewing the bottom of the iFrame so they don't see the confirmation.

Is there a way to modify the length of the iFrame once the form is submitted? Because it's embedded into an iFrame I don't know if I could add an onClick action to the submit button. If it's too difficult to modify the iFrame size, it would be sufficient to force the page to scroll to the top (just as if I added onClick="window.scroll(0,0)" to the submit button).

Here is the current code:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=FORMKEY" width="795" height="1600" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add an onClick action to the submit button on the Google Docs Form.
See this question for a solution: [iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

Comment: I'm not sure how to resize the iFrame (and I don't want to spend the time figuring it out now), but I updated the code to scroll to the top of the screen when the iFrame loads (triggers when submit button is clicked). I added `onLoad="window.scroll(0,0);"` to the iframe tag.

Comment: Thanks @NateCarrier - worked perfectly for me... http://www.gleneirasoccer.com.au/today