# How to catch an iframe redirecting?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a WebView with an iframe inside. The contents of the iframe do a redirect to another URL that doesn't allow embedding in an iframe. Not a problem, actually, I just want to start the external browser activity in this case instead. The problem is that I can't find a way to intercept the redirection. None of shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), onPageStarted() or onLoadResource() get called for the redirect, hence I get no chance to start the activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the html change the iframe tag to call some javascript function when a redirect happens

example: [iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

Comment: You'd have the javascript call something you added with `addJavascriptInterface`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough but mentioning shouldOverrideUrlLoading() and its siblings should have indicated that I'd need this functionality in Java code, not inside the browser in the iframe.

Comment: This second comment seems interesting. Thanks, I'll report back.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem, we found an even more simple solution to this than calling a javascript function.  Simply add "target= _top" to the iframe redirect (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).  Then shouldOverrideUrlLoading() will be called in the Android code.

Comment: What?  You can't set a `target` on a redirect.  Your link is to information on `a` elements, which are rather different from redirects.  I'm not familiar with the tags on this question, so I'm not certain this is about HTTP at all, but I strongly suspect this is wrong.