# Prevent iframe from loading "src" page upon refreshing

Tags: html, iframe

I'm creating a static website and I am using iframes. The problem is, when I navigate to another page, say for example, this code for the iframe:

```
<iframe marginheight="0" align=top src="aboutus1.php" frameborder=0 scrolling=no border=0 WIDTH=800  framespacing=0 id="bodyframeid" name="bodyframename" onLoad="autoResize('bodyframeid');>" ></iframe>
```

The `src` attribute is pointing to aboutsus1.php. Now, when I navigate to another page, for example, I go to aboutus2.php then I reload the page, it goes back to aboutus1.php which is executed by `src="aboutus1.php"`. My question is, how do I stay on the current page (aboutus2.php) even if I reload the page?

**EDIT:**
[Click here for live example](http://comgtech.com/cti_index.php)

Click the link above. First page you will see is `About CTI`. Now, try clicking on `Partners` menu then refresh the page. It goes back to `About CTI` page. How do I prevent it from going back to `About CTI` page when the page reload?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Can you be a little bit clearer in your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could store the current page location in a session, and on reload load the url stored in the session. But you'd need some server side technology. In just html you don't store things. You might also be able to use a GET value.

Comment: Can you please give me example.. Thanks.

Comment: You could use http://www.site.com/index.html?url=aboutus2.php, and <iframe src=\"" + <?php echo $_GET['url'] ?> + "\"> or use $_SESSION['url'] = 'aboutus2.php'; and use that as the iframe src

Answer (score 1):

You can't. By reloading the page you are loading a completely new page that just happens to come from the same resource as the previous page.

You can't avoid reloading the iframe when you are reloading the main page, but you can make it reload the same page again.

If you want to load a specific page in the iframe, you need to send information to the main page what to put in the iframe `src`. You can for example send that information in a query string, or put it in a cookie.

Comment: Would you please give me examples how to do it using cookie?

Comment: @abc123: Sorry, I don't enough PHP for that. You would set the cookie when you change the page in the iframe, and just read from the cookie to set the `src` of the iframe. You can get and set the cookie either from the client code or server code, it follows the request so it's available at both sides.

Answer (score 1):

If you have in your iframe the documents from the same domain (same origin), or you can set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers on displayed page, you can [detect iframe src change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection), and save the current URL (cookie, localStorage or anything you have), and restore it on page load.