# Detecting src/location change in a iframe object

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an iframe object pointing to a specific page. For example,

```
<iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"></iframe>
```

I want to have an alert whenever the location of the iframe changes because the user has clicked a link inside it.

Doing `onLoad="alert(this.ContentWindow.location.href);"` yields nothing.

Doing `onLoad="alert(this.src);"` yields the initial src (../wiki/Special:Random) no matter what the user has clicked.

The user will stay within the same domain, so the Same Origin policy is not violated.

Comment: Probably a typo, but your `iframe` tag isn't properly formed.

Comment: The iframe src says `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random`, yet you say the user will stay within the same domain. Are you sure this isn't a SOP issue?

Comment: Oops, sorry.  <iframe width="940" height="550" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random">    </iframe>

Comment: `onLoad="alert(this.src);"` seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cFxgZ/.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe OP wanted detect location change when link is clicked inside of Iframe document and not set directly via src

Comment: @Yuriy: Oh, I missed the "inside it" part.

Comment: Sounds like the solution detailed [in this very similar StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36040615/26510) might work for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use correct case in "ContentWindow", it's supposed to be "contentWindow".

```
<iframe src="your initial URL" onload="alert(this.contentWindow.location.href)" />
```

works.

Comment: you cannot access the `contentWindow.location` of a website that is not within the same domain or protocol of the parent window. specially on google chrome.

Comment: @HashemQolami quoting OP: *The user will stay within the same domain, so the Same Origin policy is not violated.*

Comment: Since the `src` attribute points to `http://en.wikipedia.org`, the `iframe` MUST be in en.wikipedia.org to get to work. BTW, If `user will stay within the same domain`, this should work.

Comment: @HashemQolami I can only assume that the URL shown was a random example or that OP works for Wikipedia :)

Comment: You wish :) It was definitely a random example.

Comment: @KarthikaPai So, `mydomain.com` would be a better example ;)

Comment: Oooh, I definitely get an alert but it says "undefined".

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you sure you're not making cross domain calls (try it in IE for example, you will get Permission denied if you are). Are u using relative or absolute URL for initial SRC? Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gXBLD/1/ try selectinng "Reset password" link there

Comment: I am using Chrome. My code is <iframe width="940" height="550" src="http://en.wikipedia.org" onload="alert(this.contentWindow.location.href);"</iframe>

Comment: Can you post real URL of the page hosting the IFRAME and URL used as SRC? Or, if not just replace domain with something else

Comment: Mmm ,I thought I posted it. h t t p : / / en.wikipedia.org

Comment: And I'm running this on my localhost server (Ruby on Rails app)

Comment: I thought it was a random example no? So you're saying both parent page and iframe src have main Wikipedia page  as URLs?

Comment: If your parent page is localhost and I frame is Wikipedia - it is a cross domain call and it won't work.

Comment: @KarthikaPai for postMessage to work someone has to receive the message and you do not control the inner pages. AFAIK there's no workaround due to security reasons