# How to trigger a function when iframe src change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i have iframe with src like `http://remote-domain.com/`, and when ever the src is get changed i need to trigger a function like `iframeSrcChanged()`

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://remote-domain.com/" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
```

and when user click about-us inside iframe, the iframe src get changed into

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://remote-domain.com/about-us.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
```

so this time i need to trigger `iframeSrcChanged()` function.

Please help me to trigger out this issue.

Comment: Please see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection

Answer (score 2):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

iframe.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function(event) {
    if (event.attrName == "src") {
       // The "src" attribute changed
    }
});
```

However this will work only in modern browsers

Comment: Even though this would work, using it is highly discouridged. The event won't fire in many browsers, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events and http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HwY9Q/4/ - the event will trigger, but you can get only the src property if the domain name of the iframe is different than your site's domain (the browser won't let you access the contentWindow, for security reasons).