# Picking up when the src of an iframe changes

Tags: vb.net, iframe, webforms

I have an application that loads a URL into an iframe's src attribute.

What I am trying to do, is pick up when the src attribute of the iframe changes (each time a user clicks a link within the iframe, I want to know what the link is that they have clicked).

I am working in vb.net with a .ascx file.

Here is the load function:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim frame1 As HtmlControl = CType(Me.FindControl("frame1"), HtmlControl)
    frame1.Attributes("src") = hyperLinkURL
End Sub
```

Anyone have a suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection) may help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that one. I've been led to believe that it is impossible to have an iframe be accessed when its content is https, and the accessing browser is http.