# Google Form via Iframe: google apps script onFormSubmit notification to a hosting domain?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

We have a Google Form loaded on our domain using iframe.

Using Google Apps script I'm able to make actions (send emails, fetch urls, etc) on form submit (using installable onFormSubmit event).

**Is it possible using apps script to send notification to our domain that this form is submitted?**

To better explain what we actually need: if we'd had possibility to redirect on this form submit, we would redirect a user to a specific page on our domain, internally on this page a tag is assigned to this user.

So far the only solution we could find is to insert google form directly to our page in order to avoid cross-domain troubles, which is not very convenient having different forms on different pages.

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to detect a load or reload of the Google Form in your website, and then run code to do whatever you want.  See the following Stack Overflow post: [iframe src change event detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

Comment: Thanks, Sandy. I knew I can catch load events, but thinking again about it I've got a simple idea of counting iframe loads and perform my actions on the second load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with [Google Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108080345550600771979/posts/YwyKkNQo31a?cfem=1), it seems there's no such direct way using google apps script.

Finally decided to use our domain client-side workaround counting iframe loads and making needed action on the second load, which is supposedly going to be a form submitted/iframe reloaded event.