# Is it possible to pass iframe query strings through parent URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, iframe

I have a webpage with an iframe. What I want to be able to do is have the query string from the iframe pass through the parent url.

For example:
Parent URL: `mysite.com/iframe-page`

iframe URL: `iframe.com`

When a link is clicked on in the iframe the iframe url changes to `"iframe.com/?filter=google"`

I would like it set up so that the parent url could start as mysite.com/iframe-page then when the link in the iframe is clicked the url changes to `mysite.com/iframe-page?filter=google`

Is this something that is possible to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links in the `IFRAME` can target the parent

```
<a href="mysite.com/iframe-page?filter=google" target="_parent">Google</a>
```

Once the parent page loads, it can set the `IFRAME`'s URL based on it's own query string.

```
window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('myIframe').src = 'iframe.com' + location.search };
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding and I apologize for that. Why do you have an anchor tag in your answer? I added the script you provided to my page but when I still access the page and utilize the filters I get nothing happening in the parent url

Comment: actually maybe I understand what you are suggesting. The anchor tag is within the iframe but the target has to be set to _parent within the iframe itself.

Comment: Correct, that way the link inside the IFRAME will control the parent page.

Comment: Well this sucks... the backend of the iframe site has a bug that will not allow me to add the <base target="_parent" /> tag to the head of the site. Unfortunately I do it like this because there are around 300-500 links.