# Keep track of a request that I didn't start

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I have a splash page to show users before they connect to my wifi. I want them to take a little survey before granting access, the survey is on a third party server ([questionpro.com](http://www.questionpro.com/)) and loads on my page by an iframe.

The problem is that I have no way to know if the user actually answered, because it all happens inside the iframe, I can't interact with the iframe because same-origin policy, I tried to use [iframeTracker](https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery) to detect when the user clicks the iframe, but I don't think this is ideal.

I realized the only thing that changes is the number of request on my developer tools, so, is there a way to keep track of these ones? If not, do you have any idea to make it work?

Comment: `iframe.onload=console.info.bind(console)`

Comment: sounds like you've already got some sort of web server set up, why not just create your own survey script or download one of the thousands of open source survey scripts..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection

Comment: @Pamblam I use questionpro beacuse they take care of the backend and analytics part, but yeah, creating my own script is one of my options

Comment: @Nate, Thanks! Michiel's answer did the trick