# callback function after Google Form is submitted

Tags: forms, iframe, callback, google-forms, user-experience

Hi I am embedding a Google Forms in a website, through .

I want to add a callback function to the form, so that I can now that the user submitted it, and I can close the form window (or display a button to close it).

How to do it?

I have not found such a function in GDoc Form. I saw there is a script editor, but could not make it work for me, seems overkill.

I was adding a button to my html page that is always displayed atop of the form, but actually I would like it to appear only after the user completed the form.

--
Edited

Tried [iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

but still I undergo

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
```