# Symfony FOSCKE onchange event

Tags: javascript, symfony, ckeditor, symfony-forms

I'm making a form field with FOSCKEditorBundle, which simply generates the CKEditor. The problem is, that I have to catch the onChange event on that generated editor window. I've tried with this:

```
        $builder->add('description', CKEditorType::class, array(
        'label'         => false,
        'config'        => array(
            'toolbar'   => 'basic',
            'on'        => 'change: function(){unsaved = true; console.log("changed!");},'    
        ),
    ));
```

...but no effect. I did this following the CKEditor & FOSCKEditor documentation.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/usage/toolbar.html

Is there any way to set onChange event, like from the form generation site or client site? Doesn't matter for me, but I don't want to edit the config.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:
[iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

We can fire onChange by onLoad, which fires up on every change of state in iframe generated by CKE.