# Detecting iframe src change - external website

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to detect if the iframe src changes e.g. if the iframe redirects to another page?

The website that I have embedded in the iframe is not controlled by myself, and is external - all the solutions I have seen are exclusively for those who have control over both websites.

I'm essentially wanting to detect the iframe src changing, so that I can instead redirect my own actual webpage.

I'm aware of the "Same Origin" policy - but I;m not sure if there'd be a way that wouldn't need to interfere with this.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)