# How to detect if user has submitted form from iframe

Tags: angular, angular7

Hello everyone I have an iframe displaying in a angular stepper function like this

```
<iframe id="prompt" class="first" [src]="promptHtml"></iframe>
```

the src is an external source of data.

After the User has clicked submit in the form they have to manually click "next" to get to the next step in my Angular wizard.

My question is how can I detect the user clicking submit in the iframe and then trigger some angular code to go to the next step in my process?

Comment: `onLoad` might help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection - you can then look at what's being loaded and react to that - perhaps even handling errors.

Comment: Hmm yeah that might work, ill try console logging the onLoad and seeing what responses I get. Maybe there is a different response for when the user completes the form and I can write some logic around that.