# How to detection iframe URL jump to another URL

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have a page login.php use iframe "src=http://def.com/login".

My domain is example.com.This def.com jump to http://def.com/home after logout

I want to my page catch iframe URL jump from http://def.com/home to my page http://example.com/login.php when user logout.

Comment: You can check: has the cookie variable of `def.com` url created when login, when logout then has that cookie variable removed? Then you can use that cookie variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use $_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the refresh page url, if the value is undefined or null, it is accessed directly.