# How to obtain a URL from an iframe in Angular Dart after a user interacts with the iframe?

Tags: dart, iframe, angular-dart

Let's say I have the following iframe on my website:

```
<iframe id="my-frame" src="www.espn.com"></iframe>
```

If someone where to interact the iframe and make a change where the URL inside of the iframe updated its parameters for example:

[www.espn.com?q=TEAMS:cowboys](http://www.espn.com?q=TEAMS:cowboys)

Is there a way to capture the updated URL from the iframe or the new parameters?

To give you an idea of what I am trying to do in my mind it would look something like this:

```
var myFrame = document.getElementById("my-frame");

myFrame.addEventListener('change', (event) => 
    // get URL from iframe after the URL has changed
    // example: www.espn.com?q=TEAMS:cowboys
);
```

is this possible?

Comment: did you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I gave this a go, but there are security issues in-lining onLoad in the html it seems. This must have changed since this was posted. I will see if I can find a way to work around this though and report the results!